# Charring and insulation damage on floor heat wire

Tags: electrical, wiring, floorheating

I have a floor heat system that was only working intermittently (the [thermostat](https://ojelectronics.com/floorheating/products/udg/) seemed to operate just fine, but the floor only warmed up about 25% of the days it was supposed to).

I was planning to try swapping the thermostat with another one from a different room where it's working properly, and when I pulled it out of the wall (after turning off the breaker) I found that one of the wires on the "load" side appears to be blackened:

[image]
[image]

The screw didn't seem loose, but the tip of the conductors look discolored, and the wire insulation seems stiffened (and the white wire's insulation looks a bit yellow). When I tried to bend the black wire a bit, the insulation actually cracked.

I am planning to have a professional take a look at it, but hoping to cross-reference with additional opinions:

- Was this just a bad connection (even if the screw did not seem loose) or could something else be the root cause?
- Would it be safe to cut the wires back to where there is less or no apparent heat damage, and re-strip them? Should I add any tubing or additional protection around the insulation since it seems like it has cracked in places?
- Is it possible the thermostat itself is at fault and would need to be replaced, or should I try just fixing the connection and continue using the same thermostat?

Picture inside the box for good measure:

[image]

Comment: All of the above plus maybe a problem in the floor.  Having an electrician check and test will be money spent wisely.

Answer (score 0):

These radiant resistive kits come in 120v versions and 240v versions.  If you hook up 240v to a 120v cable you'll cook the cable.  The cables have their resistance (length designed for a certain wattage).

Is your breaker 120 or 240?

Comment: The breaker has only a single switch rather than two connected to each other, so I think that means it is 120V? Otherwise I’m not sure how to check…other than turning it back on which I don’t want to do until I get someone to look at it :)

Comment: I think the best practice is to twist stranded wire counter clockwise before you put it into a screw down terminal - yours looks clockwise twisted.  Shouldn't really matter too much and your wires don't look too crazy.  I'd just trim and expose some new wire and give it a go again or you can hire an ele to do the same thing.  You can make sure there is continuity on the resistive cable but not many more tests to do really.  I had my radiant ele mat repaired with a splice kit as my original builder's ele overstapled and the cable arc'd and eventually vaporized in the concrete floor.

Comment: If you do just hook it up again I'd get an IR camera (flir has an iphone attachment) and take good pictures of the path the wire takes through your floor in case you have some kind of short / arcing taking place so that you can later possibly repair it.

Comment: Thanks. How did you repair the floor without redoing the whole thing? The floor is tiled but I don't have any spare tiles from when it was installed (years before I bought the house)...

Comment: I hired someone to use a power source that arcs ele at 40,000v which warms up the area where the fault is...  then jackhammered and exposed the cable and spliced it.  Mine was just a cable and not a mat though you could probably do the same.  Most manufacturers have repair kits.